# Publish/Unpublish in *specific* Child Publications

Tags: 2013-sp1, publishing

In Tridion 2013 SP1, is anyone aware of a way in which this setting:

**Also Publish/Unpublish in Child Publications**

could be customized to show the user a list of optional Publications?

Is this something where a plugin could help, or we could customize the GUI ourselves?

I've had a quick look around but I'm thinking that this may be too big of an ask.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Go through this blog post  https://www.whobrokethebuild.me/default-publish-settings-in-sdl-tridion/

Comment: This functionality will come OOTB in Sites 9.5. Maybe another reason for the customer to consider upgrading from an ancient/unsupported version? 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no out of the box option for this. It is either all, or some. There is no option to customize the existing GUI window to modify information during selection what needs to be done because the information about in which publications item should be published is done in Resolver after clicking on the button publish.

Now you can always construct your own publish dialog, one with the same info and functionality as existing one with this info. Then you can mimic blueprint info, and instead of sending the item in all child publications, you can send n items in each of the selected publications.

Another option is to utilize blueprint. Don't publish from the topmost item, from content master publication. Send item from parent publication for some market, or some language.